# cannot load npy file in building custom data generator of Keras

Tags: python, image, numpy, keras, deep-learning

This is the first time I have created a Custom Data Generator.I am still not very familiar with Custom Data Generators

Why np.load cannot load .npy file? Did I encounter error while creating the npy file?

All of image_folders and label_folders at data/syu/npy, I tried to use the same folder structure as ImageDataGenerator.

My image are 5 * 1channels & 1 * 3channels,I want to concatenate them to 8channels but connot concatenate on 1channel so I spread them to 3channels and concatenate to 18channels .npy file,label image do same action.

```
TypeError
expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.int32
  File "C:\Labbb\testing\unet_mao0\data.py", line 219, in get_data
    image = np.load(image_path)
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.int32
```

```
params = {'dim': (512,512), 'batch_size': 1, 'n_classes': 7, 'n_channels': 18, 'shuffle': True}
image_folders = ['image0', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3', 'image4', 'image6', 'image7']
label_folders = ['label0', 'label1', 'label2', 'label3', 'label4', 'label6', 'label7']  
data_generator = CustomDataGenerator(image_folders, label_folders, **params)
model = unet()
model_checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint('weight/syu/0123467_Custom_test1.hdf5', monitor='loss',verbose=1, save_best_only=True)
```

```
class CustomDataGenerator(Sequence):
    def __init__(self, image_folders, label_folders,dim=(512,512),  batch_size=1,n_classes=7,n_channels=18,shuffle=True):
        self.image_folders = image_folders
        self.label_folders = label_folders
        self.dim = dim
        self.batch_size = batch_size
        self.n_classes = n_classes
        self.n_channels = n_channels
        self.shuffle = shuffle
        self.image_paths = []
        self.label_paths = []

        for folder in self.image_folders:
            image_folder_path = os.path.join('data/syu/npy', folder)
            image_files = os.listdir(image_folder_path)
            for file_name in image_files:
                self.image_paths.append(os.path.join(image_folder_path, file_name))

        for folder in self.label_folders:
            label_folder_path = os.path.join('data/syu/npy', folder)
            label_files = os.listdir(label_folder_path)
            for file_name in label_files:
                self.label_paths.append(os.path.join(label_folder_path, file_name))

        self.on_epoch_end()
    def __len__(self):
        return int(np.ceil(len(self.image_paths) / self.batch_size))

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        batch_image_paths = self.image_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]
        batch_label_paths = self.label_paths[index * self.batch_size: (index + 1) * self.batch_size]

        
        batch = zip(batch_image_paths, batch_label_paths)
        
        return self.get_data(batch)
    
    def on_epoch_end(self):
        self.image_paths = np.arange(len(self.image_paths))
        self.label_paths = np.arange(len(self.label_paths))
        if self.shuffle == True:
            np.random.shuffle(self.image_paths)
            np.random.shuffle(self.label_paths)

    def get_data(self, batch):
        X = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_channels))
        y = np.empty((self.batch_size, *self.dim, self.n_classes))

        for i, (image_path, label_path) in enumerate(batch):
            image = np.load(image_path)
            label = np.load(label_path)

            X[i,] = image
            y[i,] = label

        return X, y
```

Comment: At the problem point `image_path` is a number, not a file name (a syring)

Comment: @hpaulj thank you, I have fixed the problem.I build two for loop in on_epoch_end